# Getting data from Firebase via Reference from props

Tags: reactjs, firebase, reference

I get the reference to some document via props. When my component is rendering I would like to get this data from firebase. I tried do it like this :

```
const EventListElement = props => {

    const [object, setObject] = useState(async () => {
        let object_id, object_info;
        return await props.event.obiekt.get().then(resp=>{
            object_id = resp.id;
            object_info = resp.data();
            object_info = {
                ...object_info,
                id: object_id
            }
            console.log(object_info)
            return object_info;
        })
    })

    return(
        <div className={styles.EventListElementContainer}>
            {object.nazwa_wlasna}
        </div>
    )
}

export default EventListElement;
```

but it didn't work. My data showed on `console.log()`, but didn't save in this `object` state and I can't get to them from `return()` of my component.

Comment: You aren't returning anything from the `await`'ed function to set the initial state with.

Comment: I wrote return object_info there. Should I do it in some other way ?

Comment: `return`'s don't cascade. You have to return from the `async` function too. Add `return` before the `await props.event...`

Comment: Ok, I did it, but nothing changed. Still I can see information about objects in `console.log()`, but there is nothing in state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`useState` is expecting a value to be passed in rather than an async function. Try at minimum restructuring your code to move the async operation out of the `useState()`. You can use a hook like `useEffect` to execute the async operation when props changes:

```
useEffect(async () => {
    let object_id, object_info;
    await props.event.obiekt.get().then(resp=>{
        object_id = resp.id;
        object_info = resp.data();
        object_info = {
            ...object_info,
            id: object_id
        }
        console.log(object_info);
        setObject(object_info);
    })
  }
}, [props]);

// Initialize with default value    
const [object, setObject] = useState({ nazwa_wlasna: '' });
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: OK I had to remove async and await, because of some error. After that when I display value I have to just check if object isn't null -             {object && <p>{object.nazwa_wlasna}</p>}
- and it works :P thank you